# Is it possible to set max width flag identifiers according to user input in C?

Tags: c

For a student course in c,
I want to know if it is possible to use the max width flag identifiers
as an integer you get from the user
example :
first iteration of the loop :

```
printf("%7d\n",Number)
```

second iteration of the loop :

```c
printf("%6d\n",Number)
```

Third iteration of the loop :

```c
printf("%5d\n",Number)
```

and so on... I want to know if it is possible to use something like this:

```c
int i;
int userWidthInput=10;
for(i=userWidthInput; i>1;i--)
{
    printf("%userWidthInputd\n",Number);  
}
```

Comment: Check e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it will tell you that it's not only possible, but also how to do it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Does that also apply to C? It says "C File IO" but the domain is "cppreference"

Comment: @Arc676 The http://en.cppreference.com/ site contains both C and C++ references. The link I gave is for the C reference part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not, use like

```
printf("%*d\n",width, Number);
```

So, your code might looks as follow:

```
int i;
int userWidthInput=10;
int Number = 10;
for(i=userWidthInput; i>1;i--)
{
   printf("%*d\n",i , Number);
}
```